# Как задать задержку при наведении с помощью jquery?

Tags: jquery

Когда навожу быстро несколько раз на элемент, то он появляется и исчезает циклично. Как задать задержку, чтобы в следующий раз он появился, например только через секунду?

```
var tooltip = $('.tooltip');
var title;
return this.each(function() {
      $(this).mouseenter(function() {
        title = $.trim($(this).attr('title'));
        $(this).attr('title', '');
        if (title === undefined || title === '') {
          title = $(this).text();
        }
      }).mousemove(function(e) {
        var top = e.clientY + 20;
        var left = e.clientX + 20;
        tooltip.text(title).css({
          'top': top,
          'left': left,
          'background': options.defBg,
          'color': options.defColor
        }).fadeIn(1000);
      }).mouseleave(function() {
        tooltip.fadeOut();
        $(this).attr('title', title);
      });
```

Answer (score 1):

Зачем делать паузу, если можно отключить прошлую анимацию функцией `.stop()`

```
var tooltip = $('.tooltip');
var title;
return this.each(function() {
      $(this).mouseenter(function() {
        title = $.trim($(this).attr('title'));
        $(this).attr('title', '');
        if (title === undefined || title === '') {
          title = $(this).text();
        }
      }).mousemove(function(e) {
        var top = e.clientY + 20;
        var left = e.clientX + 20;
        tooltip.text(title).stop().css({
          'top': top,
          'left': left,
          'background': options.defBg,
          'color': options.defColor
        }).fadeIn(1000);
      }).mouseleave(function() {
        tooltip.stop().fadeOut();
        $(this).attr('title', title);
      });
```